Excel file created in .NET, I need one column to be a nested, by year, then month, then day, searchable date field
EDIT: topsail has proposed the correct answer in the comments, which is stop using ToString on the DateTime types.
I have an existing C#/.NET application that updates an existing Excel spreadsheet.
The spreadsheet only has header columns for a table, and the application appends the data rows.
In the excel template I specified the format for the column to be a date type.

.

But the search field doesn't seem to understand it's a date column. When clicking on the filter dropdown, the list just a flat selection all the dates. They're not grouped by year, month, day.  Notice that the dialog says "Text Filters".



But, I've discovered that if I just perform a replace on the column. I.E.



Which doesn't actually change data, but then the filter shows the dialog I'm looking to see.



Notice that the dialog now shows "Date Filter", and the years are listed with nested months. Open a month and the days are there.

I've tried various format and calls, but I can't seem to get it right. As you can see, I'm using FlexCel.
using FlexCel.Core;
using FlexCel.XlsAdapter;
. . . 
var dateOfBirthFormat = file.GetCellVisibleFormatDef(currentRow, currentColumn);
dateOfBirthFormat.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy";
var dateOfBirthFormatId = file.AddFormat(dateOfBirthFormat);
file.SetCellValue(currentRow, currentColumn, opportunityView.DateOfBirth.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), dateOfBirthFormatId);
. . .

My question is: how do I, from C#, tell excel that I want a date column so that when it's filtered, shows the correct Date Filter options?

@topsail, that's the answer. if you add an answer, I'll selected it as correct.

When you write your value to the cell, make sure it is a date value and not a date string:
file.SetCellValue(currentRow, 
    currentColumn,opportunityView.DateOfBirth.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), dateOfBirthFormatId);

So change this to (not calling ToString() on the date):
file.SetCellValue(currentRow, 
    currentColumn,opportunityView.DateOfBirth, dateOfBirthFormatId);

Then if you also need to set cell formatting on the cells that contains these dates, that will be another operation.
